# User input not accepted, when i press enter just starts a new line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is my code:

```
v = 0
eng = ""
pig = ""
movetoend = ""
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]
while eng != "Quit this program":
    eng = input("input english: ")
    listeng = eng.split()
    if eng == "Quit this program":
        break
    for word in listeng:
        if word[0] != ("a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u" or "A" or "E" or "I" or "O" or "U"):
            while v == 0:
                for l in word:
                    if l != ("a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u" or "A" or "E" or "I" or "O" or "U"):
                        movetoend = movetoend + l
                    else:
                        v=1
                        pig = pig + l
            pig = pig + movetoend + "ay"
        else:
            length = len(eng)
            pig = eng[1:length] + "ay"
        print("pig latin is: " + pig)
print("program closed")
```

the code isn't done yet, i know it doesn't work (its for a very rudimentary pig latin converter), but my question is, why is it that when i try to run this code it doesn;t take my user input anymore and just moves the cursor to the next line?

This problem started happening when i realised I'd forgotten to indent

```
else:
    v=1
    pig = pig + l
```

by enough (it was in line with the 'for' above instead of the 'if') but when i indented it i started having this problem

Comment: One obvious misconception is that `or` returns the first truth-y value, which means that `"a" or "e" or ...` is simply `"a"`. It is a common miscconception. What you want is `word[0] not in {'a', 'e', 'i', ...}`. Even more shortly: `word[0] not in set('aeiou...')`...

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.

A `while` loop isn't necessary to complete the function and puts it into an infinite loop.

A few other edits.

You don't have to have a list  `xxx or xxx or xxx or xxx` .. simply use

`if word[0] in vowels:`  This will check each letter in the list for you.

in python you can use the `+=` to add together.

```
v += 1
pig += l     `
```

For the 2nd `while` loop , `while v == 0` , can be replaced with an `if` statement as the `for` loop is already iterating.

`if v == 0:`

You can wrap it in a function like so to keep your code easier to work with

```
def convert_word():
    v = 0
    eng = ""
    pig = ""
    movetoend = ""
    vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]
    eng = input("input english: ")
    listeng = eng.split()
    for word in listeng:
        if word[0] in vowels:
            if v == 0:
                for l in word:
                    if l in vowels:
                        movetoend = movetoend + l
                    else:
                        v += 1
                        pig += l
            pig = pig + movetoend + "ay"
        else:
            length = len(eng)
            pig = eng[1:length] + "ay"
        print("pig latin is: " + pig)

    print("program closed")        

convert_word()
```